# Why do i have a random result on this template?

Tags: c++, templates, pointers

Can someone tell my why do I have random result ?

```
template<class T, class U>
T f(T x, U y)
{ 
    return x+y;
}
int f(int x, int y)
{ 
    return x-y;
}
int main()
{ 
    int *a=new int(3), b(23);
    cout<<*f(a,b);
    return 0;
}
```

And what b(23) means ? Thank you a lot !

Comment: What "random result" are you talking about?

Comment: `*(new int(23) + 23)` is indeed UB.

Comment: i am getting different result everytime

Comment: Try to keep the declarations simpler -- one declaration at a time. `int *a = new int(3); int b(23);` That will lead to less confusion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The template instantiated will be

```
int* f(int* x, int y)
{
    return x + y;
}
```

Therefore you'll be doing pointer arithmetic, then dereferencing a pointer in which you did not allocate, which happens to be incremented 23 addresses past `a`.

It is essentially as if you'd called

```
*(new int(23) + 23);
```